# Match the n-th occurence dynamically

Tags: regex, perl

I was trying out stuff on regex101 and was asking myself:

**How** can I dynamically **match** the n-th number group.

lets take the string:

```
string = this11is22library33this44is55library
```

For **js-regex** I was able to identify the following pattern

- get 1st `(?<=(?:\d+\D+){0})\d+    #11`
- get 2nd `(?<=(?:\d+\D+){1})\d+   #22`
- get 3rd `(?<=(?:\d+\D+){2})\d+    #33`
- get 4th `(?<=(?:\d+\D+){3})\d+    #44`
- get 5th `(?<=(?:\d+\D+){4})\d+    #55`

**How** is it possible to construct such a pattern that **matches** the n-th number block in **perl** regex?

Comment: Convert them into `^(?:\d+\D+){0}(\d+)` and grab `$1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\K` for this variable-length lookbehinds (Perl supports):

```
(?:\d+\D+){3}\K\d+
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/C549Ej/1)

Comment: wow, that's exactly what I was looking for. I will learn more about the `\K` thing.